# Unable to put constraints to the included layout elements

Tags: android, android-layout

In my android app, I am trying to have a common layout having some basic components that I can reuse in multiple layouts. However, it is not working.

This is my common layout, "common_elements.xml":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/horizontalGuideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/verticalGuideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/horizontalGuideline"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/verticalGuideline"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/verticalGuideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/horizontalGuideline" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</merge>
```

I am trying to include common_elements like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".TL">

    <include android:id="@+id/horizontalGuideline" layout="@layout/common_elements" />
<!-- I have tried including an individual component as well as whole layout. 
    Both of these don't work.
    -->

    <include layout="@layout/common_elements"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/promptLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/horizontalGuideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/horizontalGuideline"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/verticalGuideline"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/verticalGuideline"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

***Observed Behaviour***

In the common layout I have things like guidelines and progressbar, which I don't want to define in each layout file. In the new layout I am trying to put constraints with respect to the guidelines defined in the included layout.

However, the elements in new layout are not honouring those constraints and are jumping to the beginning of the screen.

I have tried solutions like including merge tag, giving height/width to included layout, including just one component instead of whole layout.

None of these worked.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Remove the <merge> tag from both of your included layouts.

When you specifiy attributes on an <include> tag, the system will apply those attributes to the root view of the included layout. The <merge> tag is a special element to allow you to have multiple views in your layout without having a root view. So all of your constraints get thrown out when your included layout uses the <merge> tag. Luckily, both of your included layouts only have one view inside the merge, so you can just remove the merge altogether

Comment: I think they need it the other way 'round. They want the `Guideline`s and the `ProgressBar` to be added directly to the main `ConstraintLayout`. If that's so, remove the `<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>` in your common layout, and leave the `<merge>` tags.

Comment: @MikeM. yes I want the Guideline and ProgressBar to be included in other layout. I tried what you told, but I am getting compilation error saying ```Namespace app is not bound``` and ```AAPT: error: unbound prefix```

Comment: Copy the `xmlns:app...` and `xmlns:tools...` lines from that `<ConstraintLayout>` into the opening `<merge>` tag (though you're not currently using `tools` anywhere).

Comment: This is working! Thanks so much. How do I mark it as answered?